# Is this difference of two kernels also a kernel?

Tags: machine-learning, self-study, svm, kernel-trick

If we have two linear kernels $k1$, $k2$ over $R^2$ defined as:
$k1(x,y) = x^\mathsf{T}
\begin{bmatrix}
    3 &1 \\
    1 &5\\
\end{bmatrix}y$ and $k2(x,y)=x^\mathsf{T}y$ for all $x,y\in R^2$.
Will $k1-k2$ be a kernel?

I checked symmetric property but how to check if it is PSD or not? Is there some alternative way to show?

Comment: If we write it all out, we have
$$
k_1 - k_2 = x^\top \begin{bmatrix}3 & 1 \\ 1 & 5\end{bmatrix} y - x^\top y \\
=x^\top (A - I)y
$$ where $A=\begin{bmatrix}3 & 1 \\ 1 & 5\end{bmatrix}$.
Is $A - I$ p.s.d. or not? Why?

Comment: $A-I$ is psd as it is symmetric and have all eigenvalues +ve.

Comment: But will that imply $x^\mathsf{T}(A-I)y$ is psd?

Comment: What’s the definition of psd?

Comment: A square symmetric matrix $B\in R^{nxn}$ is psd, when $u^\mathsf{T}Bu\geq 0, \forall u \in R^n$ .
But here $y$ is not necessarily equal to $x$.

Comment: If we form a square matrix $K$ with each element $K_{ij} = k_1(x_i, x_j) - k_2(x_i, x_j)$, we can write

$$
K = X^\top (A - I) X
$$

Do you think that $u^\top K u \ge 0$? Why or why not? (Also, note that $u =0$ is excluded from the psd/pd definitions.)

Comment: That is psd, checked from https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2004136/is-xtax-p-s-d-if-a-is-p-s-d. 
So since $K$ can be expressed as $X^\mathsf{T}(A-I)X$ That makes it a valid kernel. Right?.

Comment: It's a valid kernel because $K$ is symmetric and psd. You should feel free to consolidate these comments as an answer to your own question (then you'll accrue rep for both question and answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing it out, we have $$
k_1 - k_2 = x^\top \begin{bmatrix}3 & 1 \\ 1 & 5\end{bmatrix} y - x^\top y \\
=x^\top (A - I)y
$$

and we can verify that $A - I$ is positive definite.

If we form a square matrix $K$ with each element $k_{ij} = k_1(x_i, x_j) - k_2(x_i, x_j)$, we can write

$$
K = X^\top (A - I) X
$$

So we neet to determine if $K$ is psd, which means showing that $u^\top K u \ge 0 \forall u \in \mathbb{R}^2\setminus 0$.

A simple way to do this is to write $(A - I) = R^\top R$, which we know is possible because $A - I$ is symmetric. Then we can write

$$
u^\top X^\top R^\top RXu = \|RXu \|_2^2 \ge 0
$$

because the sums of squares must be non-negative.